# How to remove items from a list dynamically?

Tags: c#

I'm making a small project to answer questions. I have 2 questions:

1. How do I remove the answers dynamically?
2. How can I move the answers up and down i.e: reorganise them?

It will look something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jcUP.jpg) and when I click on the button ( which says "A..." on the image) it will delete the Radio button and text-box respectively.

Each item(radio-button, text-box, button) is in a list and I was thinking that a click on the button will remove the items from the lists, those that are in same position/index.

The way I add those items is like this (it might help).

```
if (contar < 10)
{
    contar++;
    radioButtons.Add(new MetroFramework.Controls.MetroRadioButton());
    btnRmv.Add(new MetroFramework.Controls.MetroButton());
    for (int i = 0; i < radioButtons.Count; i++)
    {
        Textboxes.Add(new MetroFramework.Controls.MetroTextBox());
        Textboxes[i].Height = 20;
        Textboxes[i].Width = 580;
        Textboxes[i].Anchor = (System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top);
        Textboxes[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(txtPergunta.Location.X - 25, txtPergunta.Location.Y+txtPergunta.Height+ i * 25);
        PanelCentro.Controls.Add(Textboxes[i]);
        BtnAdd.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(BtnAdd.Location.X, Textboxes[i].Location.Y + 25);

        radioButtons[i].Anchor = (System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top);
        radioButtons[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(Textboxes[i].Location.X - 20, Textboxes[i].Location.Y);
        PanelCentro.Controls.Add(radioButtons[i]);

        btnRmv[i].Height = 20;
        btnRmv[i].Width = 20;
        btnRmv[i].Anchor = (System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top);
        btnRmv[i].Text = "delete";
        btnRmv[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(Textboxes[i].Location.X + Textboxes[i].Width + 20, Textboxes[i].Location.Y);
        PanelCentro.Controls.Add(btnRmv[i]);
        btnRmv[i].Click += RemoverResposta;
    }
}
```

I was using a for loop to delete the items but it never deleted the correct items (i.e: the items in the same position of the button I clicked), it deleted all.

Comment: You need to count down in a loop when removing, so that you dont end up skipping items, if you had a list A,B,B,C  and you do a count upwards, removing matches to B first would skip, 2nd would remove, and the 3rd would now say C so you count downwards.

Comment: Probably you have to refresh or rebind your data, i.e. form or GUI if it is.

Comment: It looks like you add the same text boxes multiple times. Why are your text boxes added inside the loop?

Comment: You have to be careful when deleting multiple items from a list.  You will mess up the indexing when using a for loop.  Instead you must change for loop to go from last unit to first : for (int i = radioButtons.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)

Comment: Except from creating controls incorrectly, where is the `RemoverResposta` body?